# Linux: moving files from different directories with same name into one while renaming them

Tags: linux, mv, bulk

I batch-ripped my old CDs to Track1.mp3. The problem is Each CD directory has Track1.mp3 so when I move them to /Music, they overwrite!

Is there possibly a bash script or mv command to **move** .mp3s from multiple sub-directories with the same file name into a single directory while renaming them if that name exists already under LINUX?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Linux command line tool to batch rename MP3 files based on ID3 tag info, or give random name if no ID3 info present](https://superuser.com/questions/555401/linux-command-line-tool-to-batch-rename-mp3-files-based-on-id3-tag-info-or-give)

Comment: I got them to show with this command: find . -type f -name '*.mp3' All I need now is a "move-and-rename-if-filename-exists" command following the -exec command. Something like mmv may work but don't know how to use it. Ex: find . -type f -name '*.wma' -exec (m)mv [insert-code-here]. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Most likely you will want "friendly" renames. Let's assume you have a struckture like

```
Artist1-+
        +-AlbumA-+
        |        +-Track1.mp3
        |        +-Track2.mp3
        +-AlbumB-+
                 +-Track1.mp3
                 +-Track2.mp3
Artist2-+
        +-AlbumX-+
        |        +-Track1.mp3
        |        +-Track2.mp3
        +-AlbumY-+
        |        +-Track1.mp3
        |        +-Track2.mp3
```

You would now want the single directory to contain something like

```
Artist1-AlbumA-Track1.mp3
Artist1-AlbumA-Track2.mp3
...
Artist2-AlbumY-Track1.mp3
Artist2-AlbumY-Track2.mp3
```

This can be achieved with a simple `bash` loop

```
for M in */*/*.mp3; do
  TRACK=$(basename "$M")
  ALBUM=$(basename $(dirname "$M"))
  ARTIST=$(basename $(dirname $(dirname "$M")))
  mv "$M" "$TARGET_DIR/$ARTIST-$ALBUM-$TRACK"
done
```

Comment: 3.19.0-32-generic wouldn't allow for it: "basename: extra operand" and "mv: cannot stat ‘*/*/*.mp3’: No such file or directory."

Comment: The path `*/*/*.mp3` is ment in connection with the example structure I gave - you might need to adapt it to your real structure.

Answer (score 0):

The `cp` and `mv` commands support this functionality through the `--backup` option.

From the [manual](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man1/mv.1.html):

> ```
>    --backup[=CONTROL]
>           make a backup of each existing destination file
>
>    -b     like --backup but does not accept an argument
> ```
>
> *[...]*
>
> The backup suffix is '~', unless set with --suffix or
>   SIMPLE_BACKUP_SUFFIX.   The  version
>          control  method  may  be  selected  via the --backup option or through the VERSION_CONTROL
>          environment variable.  Here are the values:
>
> ```
>    none, off
>           never make backups (even if --backup is given)
>
>    numbered, t
>           make numbered backups
>
>    existing, nil
>           numbered if numbered backups exist, simple otherwise
>
>    simple, never
>           always make simple backups
> ```

So e.g. `mv --backup=t <source_file> <dest_file>` should work.

Comment: "mv: cannot stat ‘*.mp3’: No such file or directory." This didn't work. It failed to search for files in subdirectories.

Comment: Try to write a loop around it and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

According to the linux community and commandlinefu.com, this convenient feature isn't possible whatsoever in any versions to date.

There is currently no command and no sure way via commandline to move files from multiple directories & subdirectories having the same name, into a single directory, without overwriting them.

Sources: commandlinefu.com, askubuntu.com, linuxquestions.org, superuser.com

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have a folder structure like this:

```
$ tree .
.
├── artist1
│   ├── albuma
│   │   └── Track1.mp3
│   └── albumb
│       └── Track1.mp3
└── artist two
    ├── album one
    │   └── Track1.mp3
    └── album two
        └── Track1.mp3
```

First, `cd` to the parent folder of your MP3 collection (parent folder of `artist1`).

Now if you run the following `find` command, you will see output like this:

```
$ find . -name '*.mp3' -exec bash -c 'echo mv -v "$1" /tmp/music/$(echo "$1" | sed "s/\.\///" | tr " /" "-")' bash {} \;
mv -v ./artist two/album one/Track1.mp3 /tmp/music/artist-two-album-one-Track1.mp3
mv -v ./artist two/album two/Track1.mp3 /tmp/music/artist-two-album-two-Track1.mp3
mv -v ./artist1/albuma/Track1.mp3 /tmp/music/artist1-albuma-Track1.mp3
mv -v ./artist1/albumb/Track1.mp3 /tmp/music/artist1-albumb-Track1.mp3
```

- `find` collects all paths to the MP3 files, e.g. `./artist two/album one/Track1.mp3` and passes them to `bash` via `-exec`
- `$(echo "$1" | sed "s/\.\///" | tr " /" "-")` is used to modify the output filename. `sed` removes the first `./` and `tr` converts 
  all space characters and `/` to `-`.

It is essential that you run `find` with `.` as start directory, otherwise the (relative) output path will not be modified correctly. Change `/tmp/music/` to the path of your music library.

If the output looks good to you, then remove the first `echo` and execute the command again.

Output:

```
$ find . -name '*.mp3' -exec bash -c 'mv -v "$1" /tmp/music/$(echo "$1" | sed "s/\.\///" | tr " /" "-")' babbsh {} \;
'./artist two/album one/Track1.mp3' -> '/tmp/music/artist-two-album-one-Track1.mp3'
'./artist two/album two/Track1.mp3' -> '/tmp/music/artist-two-album-two-Track1.mp3'
'./artist1/albuma/Track1.mp3' -> '/tmp/music/artist1-albuma-Track1.mp3'
'./artist1/albumb/Track1.mp3' -> '/tmp/music/artist1-albumb-Track1.mp3'
```